# Obscure exception on ios 8.1.3

Tags: ios, exception, resources

I've got a crash running my camera stress test on ipad air:

Exception Type:  EXC_RESOURCE
Exception Subtype: WAKEUPS
Exception Message: (Limit 150/sec) Observed 208/sec over 300 secs
Triggered by Thread:  0

Any ideas what kind of resource iOS is griping about?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 8 (I am assuming your using a background thread), have a limit on how many times you can do a "sleep" cycle on each thread per second. Usually having a high count means there is something wrong with your thread management skills. I have seen a similar post on this forums where the individual was using Grand Central Dispatch incorrectly. This may not be your case but if you do use GCD I recommend looking at this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1